# UITableView showing data and then immediately goes blank

Tags: uitableview, core-data

I  am using CoreData to pull data from a web service and then put it into tableview. When the view first loads the data appears in the tableview but in a split second later it all disappears. It probably has to do with the delete code (which I use to clear out the CoreData entity before I upload new data) because without that code the tableview worked. I have included all the code I am using to set up the data, load it into the table view, delete it and reload it.

The code can be found below... any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];
[self findSelectedCategories];
[self setUpData];
}


- (void) findSelectedCategories {

NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"ExploreCat"];
selectedCategoriesFilter = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
}




- (void) deleteEntityData {

NSLog(@"Delete code being called");

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetch setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ExploreView" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
[fetch setIncludesPropertyValues:NO];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *entities = [context executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];
for (NSManagedObject * exploreView in entities) {
    [context deleteObject:exploreView];

    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    };

}

[self.tableView reloadData];
}


- (void) setUpData {

//Create the string with the userID for the get request here
NSLog(@"SetUpData being called");

//Initialize AFHTTPRequestOperationManager with Dribbble API base URL
_operationManager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.karmo.com/explore/index"]];

[_operationManager GET:@"?user_id=5332bb35c9f9550b008ed49c" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    //Success - Runs if connection is made and data recieved
    [self deleteEntityData];

    //Extrat parsed JSON file into objects to prepare for Core Data import -- Should verify if I can skip and go directly into Core Data
    for (int i = 0; i < [[responseObject valueForKey:@"belief"] count]; i++) {

        NSString * topicID = [[[[responseObject valueForKey:@"belief"] valueForKey:@"topic"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"_id"];
        NSString * title = [[[[responseObject valueForKey:@"belief"] valueForKey:@"topic"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"title"];
        NSString *body = [[[[responseObject valueForKey:@"belief"] valueForKey:@"topic"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"body"];
        NSString * category = [[[[responseObject valueForKey:@"belief"] valueForKey:@"topic"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"category"];
        NSNumber * nFor = @([[[[[responseObject valueForKey:@"belief"] valueForKey:@"topic"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"nFor"] intValue]);
        NSNumber * nAgainst = @([[[[[responseObject valueForKey:@"belief"] valueForKey:@"topic"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"nAgainst"] intValue]);
        NSNumber *totalVotes = @([nFor integerValue] + [nAgainst integerValue]);
        NSString * vote = [[[responseObject valueForKey:@"belief"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"vote"];
        NSString *beliefID = [[[responseObject valueForKey:@"belief"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"_id"];
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];
        NSDate *createdAt = [dateFormat dateFromString:[[[[responseObject valueForKey:@"belief"] valueForKey:@"topic"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"createdAt"]];
        NSDate *updatedAt = [dateFormat dateFromString:[[[[responseObject valueForKey:@"belief"] valueForKey:@"topic"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"updatedAt"]];


        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
        // Create a new managed object
        NSManagedObject *newExplore = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ExploreView"
                                                                    inManagedObjectContext:context];


        [newExplore setValue:topicID forKey:@"topicID"];
        [newExplore setValue:title forKey:@"title"];
        [newExplore setValue:body forKey:@"body"];
        [newExplore setValue:category forKey:@"category"];
        [newExplore setValue:nFor forKey:@"nFor"];
        [newExplore setValue:nAgainst forKey:@"nAgainst"];
        [newExplore setValue:vote forKey:@"vote"];
        [newExplore setValue:totalVotes forKey:@"totalVotes"];
        [newExplore setValue:beliefID forKey:@"beliefID"];
        [newExplore setValue:createdAt forKey:@"createdAt"];
        [newExplore setValue:updatedAt forKey:@"updatedAt"];


        // Save the object to persistent store
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < [[responseObject valueForKey:@"topic"] count]; i++) {

        NSString * topicID = [[[responseObject valueForKey:@"topic"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"_id"];
        NSString * title = [[[responseObject valueForKey:@"topic"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"title"];
        NSString *body = [[[responseObject valueForKey:@"topic"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"body"];
        NSString * category = [[[responseObject valueForKey:@"topic"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"category"];
        NSNumber * nAgainst = @([[[[responseObject  valueForKey:@"topic"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"nAgainst"] intValue]);
        NSNumber * nFor = @([[[[responseObject valueForKey:@"topic"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"nFor"] intValue]);
        NSNumber *totalVotes = @([nFor integerValue] + [nAgainst integerValue]);
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];
        NSDate *createdAt = [dateFormat dateFromString:[[[responseObject  valueForKey:@"topic"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"createdAt"]];

        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
        // Create a new managed object
        NSManagedObject *newExplore = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ExploreView"
                                                                    inManagedObjectContext:context];


        [newExplore setValue:topicID forKey:@"topicID"];
        [newExplore setValue:title forKey:@"title"];
        [newExplore setValue:body forKey:@"body"];
        [newExplore setValue:category forKey:@"category"];
        [newExplore setValue:nFor forKey:@"nFor"];
        [newExplore setValue:nAgainst forKey:@"nAgainst"];
        [newExplore setValue:totalVotes forKey:@"totalVotes"];
        [newExplore setValue:createdAt forKey:@"createdAt"];

        NSError *error = nil;
        // Save the object to persistent store
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }



} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    //Failure

    NSLog(@"Failed to fetch shots from Karmo API!");
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Unable to Connect"
                                                   message:@"We were not able to connect to the karmo database. Some data may be out of date."
                                                  delegate:self
                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                         otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];

} ];


[self fetchData];}



- (void) fetchData {

NSLog(@"FetchData being called");

[exploreSortData removeAllObjects];
[exploreTableData removeAllObjects];
self.timeSortButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.voteSortButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
NSMutableArray *subPredicates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Fetch the recipes from persistent data store
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"ExploreView"];
exploreSortData = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

//Would probably need to call the category slelctions here. Use an if statment to capture so if non are seletced that all the categories are displayed

if ([selectedCategoriesFilter count] > 0 ) {

    for (int i = 0; i < [selectedCategoriesFilter count]; i++) {
        NSPredicate *newPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category ==[c] %@",[[selectedCategoriesFilter objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"categorySelected"]];
        [subPredicates addObject:newPredicate];

    }


    NSPredicate *combinedPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:subPredicates];

    NSArray *filterData = [[NSArray alloc]init];
    filterData = [exploreSortData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:combinedPredicate];

    NSSortDescriptor *voteDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"totalVotes" ascending:NO];

    NSMutableArray * descriptors = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:voteDescriptor, nil]mutableCopy];
    exploreTableData  = [[filterData sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors]mutableCopy];
    [self.tableView reloadData];


} else {

    NSSortDescriptor *voteDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"totalVotes" ascending:NO];

    NSMutableArray * descriptors = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:voteDescriptor, nil]mutableCopy];
    exploreTableData  = [[exploreSortData sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors]mutableCopy];
    [self.tableView reloadData];


}}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if ([[[exploreTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"beliefID"] isEqualToString:@"0"]) {

    ExploreVoteCell *cell = (ExploreVoteCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ExploreVote" forIndexPath:indexPath];


     NSDate * topicDate = [[exploreTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"createdAt"];
     NSString *currentDateString;
     NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
     [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];
     currentDateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
     NSDate *currentDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:currentDateString];
     NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
     NSDateComponents *dayComponents = [gregorianCalendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit
     fromDate:topicDate
     toDate:currentDate
     options:0];
     NSString *dayDifference = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@d", [@([dayComponents day]) stringValue]];
     NSString *voteCount = [[[exploreTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey: @"totalVotes"]stringValue];


    [cell.topicTitle setText:[[exploreTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"title"]];
    [cell.votesCount setText:voteCount];
    [cell.timeDayCount setText:dayDifference];

    return cell;

} else {

    ExploreBeliefCell *cell = (ExploreBeliefCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ExploreBelief" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRightChangeVote:)];
    gesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:gesture];

    [cell.topicTitle setText:[[exploreTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"title"]];

    return cell;

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

My first guess will be that your save calls are not synchronised somehow. Try to add your `deleteEntityData` method a completion block that will trigger the rest of the process.

You can use -

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(modalDidChange:) name:NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification object:yourManagedObjectContext];
```

and then implement -

```
- (void)modalDidChange:(NSNotification *)note
{
    NSSet *updatedObjects = [[note userInfo] objectForKey:NSUpdatedObjectsKey];
    NSSet *deletedObjects = [[note userInfo] objectForKey:NSDeletedObjectsKey];
    NSSet *insertedObjects = [[note userInfo] objectForKey:NSInsertedObjectsKey];

}
```

to track what is happening in your context.

Comment: I added the block above along with the `modalDidChange` code above and I am still seeing the same thing appearing when my `tableview` appears. Checking my logs it does appear that the `deleteEntityData` is being called after the `setUpData` and `fetchData`. However, if I move when I call the delete method from the `setUpData` to `viewDidLoad` the method appears to fire in the right order (looking at the NSLogs) but the data does not even appear in the `tableview` at all. Thoughts?

Comment: You said you added a completion block to your deleteEntityData, so how come it is completed after setUpData ? BTW why don't you use fetchedResultsController ?

Comment: I believe it was just because of where I had the NSLog in the method. But adding a NSLog to the `modalDidChange` method it looks like the delete code is being called on the correct `CoreData` objects but then is called again and it returns a bunch of `null` values. As far as the `fetchedResultsController` there is no reason I have not been using it  other then I am new to iOS programming and was probably more comfortable working with arrays. Do you think switched it over could help solve the problem?

Comment: Here is a video link to what I am seeing when I run the app http://youtu.be/kvDynYQPln8 - Hope that helps

Comment: @user2939977 sorry I am not near computer, for now I will say that I do recommend you to use fetchedResultsController, it is not so hard to understand and it will simplify your logic. Basically it tracks the changes that you make in the context and takes care of the TableView updates for you. Look here http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller